# Return data from object and show in <ul> via AngularJS

Tags: javascript, .net, json, angularjs, get

I have a controller that receive from server the JSON below:

```
"[{\"nome\": \"Ricardo Andrade\"}]"
```

My controller is removing the \ by parsing the JSON, my controller is:

```
app.controller("userLogado", function ($scope, $http) {

    //$http.get('web/core/components/home/nav.json').
    $http.get('http://localhost:2099/api/autenticacao/NomeUsuarioLogado').
     success(function (data) {

         debugger;
          var result = json_parse(data);

          var sNome = '';

          $.each(result, function(key, item) {

              sNome = item.nome;
          });


      })
});
```

My question is, how can I take the result of this controller and show in my HTML using AngularJS?

I tried to use an Alert and got the right name like this: "Ricardo Andrade".

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Its as simple as putting attaching the result to the controller. 
Once you get the result you want, just attach it to scope.

```
app.controller("myCtrl", function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.result = "Ricardo Andrade"
});
```

And the HTML

```
<div ng-controller="myCtrl">
{{result}}
</div>
```

If you have more than one name, you will need to ng-repeat the names.

```
<div ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <ul ng-repeat='name in result'>
    <li>{{name}}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="names in result">
    [{{$index + 1}}] {{names.nome}}
  </li>
</ul>
```

Have a look at ngRepeat:

Docs: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat

W3Schools: http://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_directives.asp

EDIT:

I hear it's better to use ng-repeat with arrays, so you might want to do that if you feel like it:

Your controller:

```
$scope.allNames =[];
app.controller("userLogado", function ($scope, $http) {

//$http.get('web/core/components/home/nav.json').
$http.get('http://localhost:2099/api/autenticacao/NomeUsuarioLogado').
 success(function (data) {

    debugger;
    var result = json_parse(data);

    for(var name in result) {                   
        $scope.allNames.push(angular.copy(result[name]));
    }          

  })
});
```

Your HTML:

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="names in allNames">
    [{{$index + 1}}] {{names.nome}}
  </li>
</ul>
```

The ul list must be inside a container with ng-controller attribute.

E.g.

```
<div ng-controller="userLogado">
 <ul list here>
</div>
```

The benefit of using an array with ng-repeat is that you can filter ([Read here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$filter)) and order ([Read here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy)) your data.